# Jquery UI: Set draggable element's drop position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

When dropping a draggable item implemented with jQuery UI, is there a way to define which part of the draggable item is used to determine the drop target position/element?

E.g. I am moving a 100x100 div in a table formed of 100x25 cells. Right now, the target cell seems to be determined by the center of the helper div. I would like the target cell to be the one at the top of the div.
This is a calendar view where the table's columns are days and rows are times. The div represents an event, and it can vary in height depending on the length of the event. It is important that when dragging an event around, the user knows where it will drop so that the time is right. Currently, if the user drops a 2-hour event so that the top is at 08:00, the target cell will end up being the one at 09:00.
I could make the visual helper element smaller while it's being dragged to help with the targeting, but I would prefer to keep it full-sized.

Visual aid (black boxes representing events):
[image: Visual aid]

My current implementation:

```
$(this).draggable({snap: 'td.dropTd', snapTolerance: "10"})
```

EDIT:
Here is a code example. The console prints the cell that the element is dropped to.
https://jsfiddle.net/akrzpvb2/2/

Comment: Suspect Snap or Grid would help. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Added a minimal code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following code.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/r8h0asL3/4/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    $('tbody').append('<tr><td id="a-' + i + '""></td><td  id="b-' + i + '""></td></tr>');
  }

  $('.dragDiv').draggable({
    containment: $("tbody"),
    snap: 'td',
    snapMode: 'inner',
    snapTolerance: "15"
  });
  $('tbody td').droppable({
    accept: '.dragDiv',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      ui.draggable.css({
        top: "",
        left: ""
      }).appendTo(this);
    }
  });
});
```

You can see here that the `snap` methods you tried were on the right path. I added `containment` so that the User can't drag it out of the schedule.

For `drop`, we need to remove the position styling and then append it to the drop target.

Moving forward, you might consider floating the DIV over the table. This way it can "cover" the time frames versus being an element inside a cell.

Comment: That's not quite what I was looking for, unfortunately. Sorry if I was accidenally misleading. Let me elaborate: The cosmetic aspect is not important, I need the td where the event starts after it's been dragged. This will be used by the code for saving the event's data.

Comment: @LittlePy more like: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/r8h0asL3/72/

Comment: That first suggestion was the one I went with, and it worked well once I adapted it to my project. Thank you very much!